# How to Update multiple Map List in Dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

```
{
  "Attributes": {
    "hero": "shyam",
    "stateinfo": [
      {
        "name": "baaaaa",
        "id": 28
      },
      {
        "name": "baaaaa",
        "id": 30
      }
    ],
    "Movie_id": 30,
    "director": "vijay"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance. I am new to DynamoDB. This is my code (see above). I have to update the map list under `stateinfo` when I only have the `id`.

For example:- if I have `id: 30`, I have to update the name value corresponding to that id.

Comment: can I show you code which you tried?

Comment: Yes Thank you, Please help to find the solution for this.

Comment: yeah for that I want to see your code then only will rectify it

Comment: var params = {
    TableName: "Cinema",
    Key: {
        "Movie_id":30,
      },
    UpdateExpression: "SET #st = :label",
    ConditionExpression: "stateinfo.id = :val2",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { 
        "#st": "stateinfo.name",
     },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
        ":label": "raj",
         ":val2": 28
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
};

docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});